# Export a function from a function

Tags: node.js, events, express, couchbase

I have an ExpressJS app where I have `api.js` in routes that manages connecting to Couchbase and then emits event `couchbaseConnected` that is awaited by `init()` function inside `api.js`.

Inside `init()` I want to push those `exports.someFunction(req, res){return something;}`. But when I just put these exports inside `init()` function, I get an error `.get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]` so it seems like I am doing it wrong.

The question is how I can export functions from another function in NodeJS?

Here is the code:

```
//connecting to couchbase and emitting event on connection
couchbase.connect(dbConfiguration, function (err, bucket) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
    cb = bucket;
    eventEmitter.emit('couchbaseConnected');
});

//listening for the event and fire init() when it's there 
eventEmitter.on('couchbaseConnected', function (e) {
  console.log('Connected to Couchbase.'.green);
  init();
});

function init() {
 exports.getUserData = function (req, res) {
  if (req.user != undefined && req.user.meta != undefined) {
    res.json(200, {result: 'ok'})
  }
  else {
    res.json(401, {error: 'Unauthorized request.'})
  }
};
}
```

Here is the ExpressJS .get() that is located in `app.js`:

```
app.get('/api/user/data/:type', api.getUserData);
```

Comment: Show us that "push" code. Currently it just looks like a syntax error.

Comment: Where are you calling `.get()`? Show us the line that throws the error.

Comment: Is .get() run before api.init?

Comment: Are you calling connect when you start your app?

Answer (score 1):

> Here is the ExpressJS .get() that is located in app.js:
>
> ```
> app.get('/api/user/data/:type', api.getUserData);
> ```

The error message `.get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]` makes quite clear what happens: You require the API module, it starts to connect to the db, you are defining your express app by passing a non-existent property to `.get` - which fails, since `init` has not yet been called and `getUserData` has not yet been assigned. What you need to do is

```
var api = require('api');
eventEmitter.on('couchbaseConnected', function () {
    app.get('/api/user/data/:type', api.getUserData); // now it is available
});
```

However, this does not look like good code. Instead of loosely coupling them via that `couchbaseConnected` event you better should use explicit callbacks that are invoked with the requested values (i.e. the `cb` bucket, or the `getUserData` method). At least pass them as parameters to the emitted event.

Also, your setup is unconventional. I don't see why `getUserData` would need to be asynchronously defined - it should always be available. If the couchbase connection failed, I would not expect the `/api/user/data/` service to *not exist*, but to *respond* with some 500 internal server error message.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer that I have made some assumptions as the data provided by you is not sufficient to know what you are doing when you start your app.

I would suggest some change in code:

```
module.exports.connect = function(callback){
   couchbase.connect(dbConfiguration, function (err, bucket) {
      if (err) {
         console.log(err);
         callback(err);
      }
      cb = bucket;
      module.exports.getUserData = getUserData();
      callback(err); //just callback with no error as you don't require to send the database 
   });
}

function getUserData(req, res){
    if (req.user != undefined && req.user.meta != undefined) {
         res.json(200, {result: 'ok'})
    }
    else {
         res.json(401, {error: 'Unauthorized request.'})
    }
};
```

and in your app.js file where you are starting the app just do this

```
var api = require('./api');
api.connect(function(error){
    if (error) throw error;
    app.listen(3000);
    console.log('Express started on port 3000');
});
```

And then you can continue doing exactly what you were doing. It should work.

I have assumed that you are not explicitly calling the connect or its equivalent when you are starting the app.....So your getting that error.